# XeTeX, microtype and fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec, microtype, protrusion

I am using XeTeX from TL2010 with microtype 2.5 beta and fontspec. My main font is Linux Libertine O. I do not see a single difference with and without including the microtype package.

Am I doing something wrong, is there a better way to optimize character protrusion in XeTeX to get nicer paragraphs and spend less time fixing overfull lines?

This is what I'm doing:

```
% This line doesn't change anything at all
\usepackage[protrusion=true,final]{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}    
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}                               
% other fonts and settings...
```

The logs do indicate that microtype seems to work:

```
LaTeX Info: Redefining \microtypecontext on input line 54.                      
Package microtype Info: Character protrusion enabled (level 2).                 
Package microtype Info: Using default protrusion set `alltext'.                 
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of tracking.                              
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of spacing.                               
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of kerning.
```

**Edit:**
Actually, protrusion does work properly it seems, but it doesn't seem to help with overfull lines. Does protrusion not help with it, and is it only font expansion that helps with overfull lines?

Comment: You have to prepare a configuration file; there are examples in the same directory as `microtype.sty` and one [for an OpenType font here](http://faculty.virginia.edu/OldEnglish/secret/mt-Junicode.cfg).

Comment: That's what I feared :-) Can I find an existing configuration file for Linux Libertine anywhere? If not, what are all the numbers and how do I choose/set them?

Comment: I tried loading `microtype` both before and after fontspec with Linux Libertine O, and character protrusion works (I compile it with XeLaTeX TeXLive2010 version), as can be viewed by loading `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`

Comment: @henrique: Indeed, it works using the default profile. I edited my question to actually mean that overfull boxes don't seem to be fixed, but is it font expansion that does that?

Comment: Protrusion means that characters like point, hyphen, comma stick a bit in the margin to get a visually more pleasant result. It changes line breaking so it can in some paragraphs improve it (like rewriting a text can improve it). But to improve line breaking in the complete text you need font expansion or you must adjust the hyphenation.

Comment: Thanks @Ulrike, that was indeed my understanding of it. And from what I understand, font expansion is not available in XeTeX currently, right?

Comment: font expansion is not available in XeTeX

Comment: Is it planned to add it?

Comment: @Raphink: Yes, but development of XeTeX has slowed to glacial dimensions - don't hold your breath waiting for it.

Comment: @Martin: oh, why is that? Is LuaTeX also frozen?

Comment: @Raphink: Jonathan Kew is working on other things, I think. In contrast LuaTeX is quite fluid. :-)

Comment: I think I've understood LuaTeX also has native unicode support and support for systems fonts (TTF and OTF). Can it full replace XeTeX?

Comment: @Raphink: The only thing that XeTeX does and LuaTeX doesn't is inclusion of PostScript. And the LaTeX support for LuaTeX is a bit behind (most notably polyglossia doesn't work). Otherwise: Yes.

Comment: `microtype` is not magic. It will help with paragraph breaking, but only _help_. You're still supposed to fix your text when the computer can't do it. See [http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=overfull](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=overfull).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking more closely, I do see that protrusion works (now that I know what it's supposed to do) and I understand that font expansion doesn't (yet) work with XeTeX. This question is thus solved.