# MnSymbol fails with `\mathcal`?

Tags: xetex, errors, mnsymbol

Let me first give you this minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{minimal}
\usepackage[retainmissing, abx]{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\[ \mathcal{ABC 123} \]
\end{document}
```

I'm compiling that with `xelatex`.

It seems, MnSymbol fails with the `abx` option when doing a `\mathcal{}` command.
I get many errors, but they all look pretty much the same:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexmf mathcm10
! I can't find file `mathcm10'. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input mathcm10 Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input mathcm10 Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: mathcm10.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input mathcm10' failed to make mathcm10.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

So, where do I go from here? should I just not use **MnSymbol** with `abx`?

Comment: First if all you shouldn't use `MnSymbol` with XeLaTeX. I'll try to find the thread.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152714/possible-to-use-mnsymbol-with-luatex http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72948/xelatex-mathspec-and-microtype-weird-error-messages

Comment: The package has a few bugs; the font name should be `mathc10`, not `mathcm10`; also, `mathabx` has no bold font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `MnSymbol` has very dubious code:

```
\DeclareOption{abx}{%
  \def\Mn@Load@Cal@Font{%
    \DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{mathc}{}%
    \DeclareFontShape{OT1}{mathc}{m}{n}{ <-> mathcm10 }{}%
    \DeclareFontShape{OT1}{mathc}{b}{n}{ <-> mathcb10 }{}%
    \DeclareMathAlphabet\mathcal{OT1}{mathc}{m}{n}%
    \SetMathAlphabet\mathcal{bold}{OT1}{mathc}{b}{n}}}
```

There is no `mathcm10` font in the `mathabx` distribution. There are no bold fonts either, so it's absurd to define a bold font.

The relevant font is called `mathc10`, so you're done with

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[retainmissing]{MnSymbol}

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{mathc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{mathc}{m}{n}{ <-> mathc10 }{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathcal{OT1}{mathc}{m}{n}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\[ \mathcal{ABC 123} \]
\end{document}
```

This is the font table for `mathc10`

[image]

Comment: Well, I like `MnSymbol` because it defines a lot of very nice symbols. Is this pretty much the only way to get the symbols? Is there a "best practice" how to do this?

Comment: @polemon See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36006/how-can-i-use-a-symbol-provided-by-a-package-without-changing-the-entire-mathema for how to import individual symbols.  I amplified a little bit on that excellent answer, with my answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132453/typing-following-notation-in-latex/132456#132456

Comment: Am I right in the assumption, that it is somewhat of an oversight on the developer's side?

Comment: I wouldn't talk about oversight: it's just a plain error.

Comment: Whether best practice or not, it works for me, and solves my particular problem. Thanks.

Comment: One other thing, though: Is it possible to make caligraphic numbers available as well?

Comment: @polemon I'll add the font table for `mathc10`, so you can see what's available.