# Lowercase bold calligraphic letters with \mathscr

Tags: fonts, bold, letters, calligraphy

On the page https://calligraphycalligraphy.blogspot.com/2020/11/50-calligraphy-font-latex.html?m=1, I found a lowercase calligraphic letter style, which I would like to implement in my LaTeX document. I am enclosing the image of the desired characters:

[image]

Could you please help me how to write such letters in LaTeX?  I am interested in both the plain and the boldface versions.

**Update:**

One of the users draw my attention to the following solution ([How to make calligraphic numbers available with `unicode-math`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184686/how-to-make-calligraphic-numbers-available-with-unicode-math)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX, bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range={\mathscr,\mathbfscr,\mathcal,\mathbfcal}]{Cambria Math}
\def\Lcs#1{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}

\begin{document}\noindent
\Lcs{mathscr}: $\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$\\
\Lcs{mathscr}: $\mathscr{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$\\
\Lcs{mathbfscr}: $\mathbfscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$\\
\Lcs{mathbfscr}: $\mathbfscr{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$

\noindent
\Lcs{mathcal}: $\mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$\\
\Lcs{mathcal}: $\mathcal{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$\\
\Lcs{mathbfcal}: $\mathbfcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$\\
\Lcs{mathbfcal}: $\mathbfcal{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$

\end{document}
```

Nevertheless, this code cannot be compiled under Overleaf.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make calligraphic numbers available with \`unicode-math\`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184686/how-to-make-calligraphic-numbers-available-with-unicode-math)

Comment: @Sebastiano I have updated my question. Could you please reflect to this problem?

Comment: You need to load to Overleaf `xits` package. Ask its team for support, if you need it.

Comment: xits is available on overleaf but Cambria Math is not licenced for free use on non windows platforms so isn't available and can't be uploaded to overleaf which is a linux system if you remove `\setmathfont[range={\mathscr,\mathbfscr,\mathcal,\mathbfcal}]{Cambria Math}` the example runs without error at Overleaf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for posting your comment. Unfortunately, by removing the indicated row does not solve the problem. Nevertheless, I am now trying to use the font of `eulervm`. Could you please help me how to define a separate math font family from the font of this package, without forcing this font type to all letters? See my question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621699/how-to-use-the-eulervm-font-only-for-a-few-letters-in-math-mode.

Comment: @TobiR I have removed the duplicate. Regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks. Perhaps you may look at my another question regarding `eulervm: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621699/how-to-use-the-eulervm-font-only-for-a-few-letters-in-math-mode. ˛Is there any way to define a separate math font family from the font of this package?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Very kind TobiR, unfortunately here not is a chat and I think that you asking me for another question. However David Carlisle is between the guru(s) of TeX/LaTeX.

Comment: the problem here is commercial not technical you are using Cambria Math and that isn't available unless you buy it.