# Italicizing emphatic speech: Italic or upright quotation marks?

Tags: typography, italic, emphasis

This is a typography question. I'm not sure if it's on-topic here; please feel free to migrate to a more appropriate site if necessary.

I'm typesetting [HPMOR](http://hpmor.com/) for private amusement, and the online text is typographically fairly liberal. I might like to edit my version to be a little more consistent, and this situation came up:

When someone speaks emphatically and I want to style this with italics, and the *entire* speech is emphasized, do the quotation marks get emphasized, too?

Example:

```
He said, ``don't \emph{look} at it.''      % this is fine
She said, \emph{``Why not?''}              % like this?
He replied, ``\emph{I don't know!}''       % or like this?
```

Comment: Logically, I would not since you are quoting emphatic speech rather than emphasising the quotation. If you were emphasising the quotation (for some reason), that might be different. On the other hand, some traditions prefer Illogical Punctuation so I don't know whether this is correct or, if it is, whether it is also correct where you are.

Comment: From a logical standpoint, you wouldn’t include them in the emphasization. Typographically speaking, you do include them. (This also may depend on the language you are writing in.) Just look at your example how `“` and `I` as well as `!` and `”` look together: Straight vs slanted, horizontal spacing (`“` and `I` are far away from each other, `!` and `”` are very close).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: The font I have works really well either way, so that's not a problem. Doesn't Bringhurst even say that it makes no sense to italicize punctuators? He strongly argued to *always* use upright parentheses, for example, so the same could probably be said of quotation marks...

Comment: My system is that the punctuation marks should only be italicised if the *whole* phrase/clause/sentence they delimit is italicised.

Comment: Not to detract from your effort (on the contrary!) – but you’re certainly aware that there are already properly typeset versions, right? If I might offer a suggestion: what’s really missing is an Open Source version that invites collaboration – i.e. having a source published on GitHub and soliciting pull requests. (That said, even just having a *properly* typeset version would be nice. The current PDF is certainly far from perfect, and the ebook versions are little more than plain text.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I'm only aware of one (the one linked on the page), and it looks awful. I could settle for a high-quality online version (a quality like these [online Lovecraft texts](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/)), or TeX source, but until such effort is authorized by the creator, it's back to XSLT and sed for me.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Actually, I misremembered. The existing PDF actually looks pretty decent. And seems to handle the quotation marks consistently. Thanks.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Ah, the tex source [is indeed available online](https://github.com/bogdanb/hpmor)! And rather well edited, it seems.

Comment: @Kerrek Oh I didn’t know that! That’s actually rather cool. I’m not sure I agree with “rather well edited”, though. And apparently contains bugs: protrusions from the `microtype` package are active, but when you look at the PDF you see that they’re actually not present (that was one of the first things I checked in the PDF).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I just discovered that microtype and xelatex have moved on since I last checked. Maybe someone should post the requisite version [on this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/xetex-microtype-and-fontspec). The editing is at least somewhat uniform (e.g. small caps, a.m./p.m. styling, quotation marks), though I haven't looked in great detail; personally, I would like to apply much heavier pruning shears to all the dashes, ellipses and hyperemphases, but... one thing at a time, I suppose. The legal situation is unclear to me, too.

Comment: I'm afraid this really isn't a technical question, so I've closed. I suspect you might be better asking about it for example on the English or Graphic Design sites.

Comment: @JosephWright: Fair enough; could you migrate it to Graphic Design please?